# Endomorphism rings of commutative algebraic groups are Noetherian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a smooth connected commutative algebraic group over an algebraic closed field $K$. By an endomorphism of $G$, we mean a homomorphism $G \to G$ in the category of algebraic groups. As $G$ is commutative, we can form the ring End($G$) of endomorphisms of $G$ .

My question is the following: is it true that End($G$) is always (left or right) Noetherian?

It is well known that if $G$ is an abelian variety then End($G$) is a free abelian group of finite rank. It follows that End($G$) is Noetherian as a ring.

If $G$ is a connected commutative complex linear algebraic group then $G\simeq \mathbb{G}_a^r\times \mathbb{G}_m^s$ for some $r,s\in \mathbb{N}$. 
Using this, we can see that End($G$) is also a Noetherian ring.

What about the general case? Can we use Chevalley's structure theorem for algebraic groups to say something about End($G$)?

Thank you in advance.